# Unable to get property of undefined or null reference UWP

Tags: javascript, windows-phone, uwp

I have the following code in my visual studio and it works perfectly well au a UWP app on my desktop win10, albeit it does not work on my windows phone as a UWP app. I also tried running my simple webapp as from a webserver and loading it in the Edge and it works perfectly. 
What should be the problem?
My code looks like this. I omitted some parts:

```
var model = {
    db: {},
    goalsobj: {},
    goals: [],
    init: function() {
        var openReq = window.indexedDB.open("GoalsDB");
        openReq.onupgradeneeded = function (event) {
            model.db = event.target.result;
            var objectStore = model.db.createObjectStore("Goals", { keyPath: "id" });
            objectStore.createIndex("id","id", {unique:true});
        };
        openReq.onsuccess = function (event) {
            model.db = event.target.result
            model.db.transaction("Goals", "readonly").objectStore("Goals").count().onsuccess = function (event) {
                if (event.target.result == 0) {
                    console.log("indexeddb empty");
                    var goalstemplate = {
                        id: "idee",
                        goals: [{ "name": "Task1" }, { "name": "Task2" }, { "name": "Task3" }]
                        }
                    var addReq = model.db.transaction("Goals", "readwrite").objectStore("Goals").add(goalstemplate);
                } else {
                    model.db.transaction("Goals", "readonly").objectStore("Goals").get("idee").onsuccess = function (e) {
                        model.goalsobj = e.target.result;
                        //console.log(e.target.result);
                        model.goals = model.goalsobj.goals;
                        goalfunc.makeList(); //model should not talk to view, but this case it is amust, because if I remove this, it does not render at boot.
                        }

                }

            }
    openReq.onerror = function (event) {
        console.log("Operation failed");
    }

}
    },
    add: function(goalname) {
        model.goals.push(
            {
                "name": goalname
        });
        model.savedb();
    },
    move: function (id,updown) {
        if (updown == "up") {
            model.goals.splice((id-1), 0, model.goals.splice(id, 1)[0]);
        };
        if (updown == "down") {
            model.goals.splice((id+1), 0, model.goals.splice(id, 1)[0]);
        };
    },
    savedb: function(){ 
        //console.log(goals);
        var update = model.db.transaction("Goals", "readwrite").objectStore("Goals").put(model.goalsobj);
        update.onerror = function (event) {
            console.log(event);
        };

},
};
```

Now When I rund this cond on my device it sais: 
Unhandled exception at line 28, column 25 in ms-appx-web://1318f74a-397e-4958-aa6b-c8d11b7c5dce/js/main.js

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'goals' of undefined or null reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested your code in my device (Device: Microsoft RM-1118  OSVersion:WindowsMobile 14393). It is working fine. As you can see I placed a button on the html page. The action of button click will execute `model.init()`, and then I set a break-point at `model.goals = model.goalsobj.goals;`. When click button the second time and `model.goals` will be set right value.

So I think the issue may happen in your target device or your `GoalsDB` was destroyed. Because the cause of `Unable to get property 'goals' of undefined or null reference` is that `model.goalsobj` was not set right value. Please check whether those operations have changed your database structure, such as moving operation. You can show more detail about your target device, and I will help you.

```
(function () {
    document.getElementById("createDatabase").addEventListener("click", createDB, false);
    function createDB() {   
        model.init();
    }
})();
var model = {
    db: {},
    goalsobj: {},
    goals: [],
    init: function () {
        var openReq = window.indexedDB.open("GoalsDB");
        openReq.onupgradeneeded = function (event) {
            model.db = event.target.result;
            var objectStore = model.db.createObjectStore("Goals", { keyPath: "id" });
            objectStore.createIndex("id", "id", { unique: true });
        };
        openReq.onsuccess = function (event) {
            model.db = event.target.result
            model.db.transaction("Goals", "readonly").objectStore("Goals").count().onsuccess = function (event) {
                if (event.target.result == 0) {
                    console.log("indexeddb empty");
                    var goalstemplate = {
                        id: "idee",
                        goals: [{ "name": "Task1" }, { "name": "Task2" }, { "name": "Task3" }]
                    }

                    model.db.transaction("Goals", "readwrite").objectStore("Goals").add(goalstemplate);

                } else {
                    model.db.transaction("Goals", "readonly").objectStore("Goals").get("idee").onsuccess = function (e) {

                        model.goalsobj = e.target.result;
                        //console.log(e.target.result);
                        if (model.goalsobj.goals != undefined) {
                            model.goals = model.goalsobj.goals;
                        } else {
                            console.log(e.target.result);
                        }

                       //goalfunc.makeList(); //model should not talk to view, but this case it is amust, because if I remove this, it does not render at 
                    }
                }
            }
            openReq.onerror = function (event) {
                console.log("Operation failed");
            }
        }
    },
    add: function (goalname) {
        model.goals.push(
            {
                "name": goalname
            });
        model.savedb();
    },
    move: function (id, updown) {
        if (updown == "up") {
            model.goals.splice((id - 1), 0, model.goals.splice(id, 1)[0]);
        };
        if (updown == "down") {
            model.goals.splice((id + 1), 0, model.goals.splice(id, 1)[0]);
        };
    },
    savedb: function () {
        //console.log(goals);
        var update = model.db.transaction("Goals", "readwrite").objectStore("Goals").put(model.goalsobj);
        update.onerror = function (event) {
            console.log(event);
        };
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks! i managed to get a different device and it works well.